Flexcard datatable condition not working
I am using a flexcard to display a data table and I am using a condition on the table to display only those where CaseStatus = New, however, it seems to totaly ignore the condition. Here is a json node from the training org:
{
    "CaseDescription": "Customer requires a shipment be canceled.",
    "CaseOpenDate": "2023-10-05T18:13:47.000Z",
    "CaseId": "500Hn00001cSXpHIAW",
    "CaseSubject": "Cancel Shipment",
    "CaseNumber": "00001049",
    "CaseStatus": "Closed",
    "DateClosed": "2022-03-11T20:15:08.000Z"
}


As far as I understand you cannot filter data displayed by the datatable in the datatable properties tab itself.
The Conditions section available is used to hide or show the element based on criteria that you enter.
I would suggest you change the Data Source of the Flexcard (be it an Integration Procedure, Dataraptor etc.) to only return Case records that have Status = New. That way the data JSON has the correct data and the datatable will display it correctly.
Good luck!

Thank you for the suggestion - this was my last resort :( I was trying to do it with one extract and filter at the presentation level with appropriate data. However, that does not seem to be working. I am going to open a case because it should work and I want to find out if this is a known issue. In the mean time I will use child cards with separate dataraptors.

@michelleemanuel good luck! Do you mind marking my answer as the preferred one? Thanks
